# Electrostatic ion thruster neutralizers

Tags: electrostatics, plasma-physics, propulsion

All electrostatic Ion thrusters have a neutralizer electron beam, but why are they required? Is avoiding the accumulation of negative charge the only reason?

I would've thought that the main reason for the neutralizer beam is to avoid the ions from bouncing back toward the grid, but this reason is never mentioned in discussions and explanations of electrostatic thrusters that I've found.

If you avoid the neutralizer altogether, and/or reduce your negative charge by throwing your electron in some other direction **which for the purpose of the proposed scenario, let's assume the electron beam is sent just ahead of the ship (180º to the ion beam). So we can consider the problem of ion electrostatic interaction with the thruster alone and ignore the problem of net spaceship charge**, *Can the ions reach escape velocity only with the electrostatic impulse? or will they sooner or later come back to the grid?*

Comment: @diffeomorphism - Without the electron return current, you effectively have a sphere emitting positively charged ions.  Since the sphere is not grounded (it's in space), it will continue to charge negative until the negative potential is greater than the energy of the exiting ions.  At this point, the ions will no longer be able to leave the sphere and you will reach a "stable" negative charge (assuming no arcing or thermal plasma currents from background act to balance the charge), which means you will have no thrust.

Comment: @honeste_vivere, for the purpose of the proposed scenario, let's assume the electron beam is sent just ahead of the ship (180º to the ion beam). So we can consider the problem of ion electrostatic interaction with the thruster alone and ignore the problem of net spaceship charge

Comment: @diffeomorphism - Then you need only balance momentum and energy.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is - is not enough to put the accelerator grid at negative potential, if the emitter grid is at zero potential, they'll never reach escape velocity. I need to put the emitter grid at a high positive potential as well. I'm so dumb. But I'm so happy that I realise that now. Thanks for the brainstorming!

Comment: Actually my problem were my boundary conditions, I set the Dirichlet conditions at the far boundary to zero potential, so when ions where approaching the boundary they felt a fictious bouncing electric field from the boundary which was because I made it too close to the grid

Comment: I deleted a comment discussion involving several inappropriate comments. Everyone remember to [be nice](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)!